# How to open a EC2 instance port on local browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running solr on port 8983 of an EC2 instance. But I'm unable to open the solr interface in my browser using:

```
http://public-dns:8983
```

I also tried using:

```
http://ip.of.ec2.instance:8983
```

But noth of them don't work.

How can I open it on my web browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the server is running, you probably forgot to open the port in the security group.

1. Check what security group your EC2 instance is
2. Open the security group
3. Add the TCP port 8983 and save it
4. Test again

Additionally, you can test whether you can access port 8983 remotely, ie. on the server itself. E.g. using telnet or so.

Good luck.

Comment: I added a "custom TCP rule" with source "0.0.0.0/8983". But its prompting me for port-range. What should I enter in the port-range field

Comment: Assuming that you are in the AWS console:

* Go to Security Groups
* Open the security group of your server (e.g. default)
* Tab Inbound
* Custom TCP Rule
* Port Range: Just 8963
* Source is just 0.0.0.0/0 (means: who can access it in CIDR format, with 0.0.0.0/0 *everyone* can access your site on this port)

Hope this helps